# jQuery tipsy click event not working

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to build a click event on images which has a tipsy hover caption however the click event is not working in IE (8 only one tested).

Below is in a PHP while loop to create a tooltip for each colour element.

```
$(function(){
    $('.colour_tip_<?php echo($f['colour_id']); ?>').tipsy({fallback: "<?php echo($f['colour']); ?>", gravity: 's'});
});
```

Its like the caption is blocking the click event.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We don't know what tipsy is, you'll have to tell us. Also, instead of the loop, just give them all the same class, and do it that way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery tipsy not firing onclick IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723057/jquery-tipsy-not-firing-onclick-ie)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".colour_tip_<?php echo($f['colour_id']); ?>").attr('title','What ever text you want');  
$(".colour_tip_<?php echo($f['colour_id']); ?>").tipsy({trigger: 'manual', gravity: 'n'});
```

Then when you know you have to show this tipsy, like onClick on those events, define onclick function of those images as:

```
$(".colour_tip_<?php echo($f['colour_id']); ?>").tipsy("show");
//also if you need to hide them on click/onfocus you can use this:              
//$(".colour_tip_<?php echo($f['colour_id']); ?>").attr('onclick', "hideTipsyOnMe(this);");
```

where hideTipsyOnMe is

```
function hideTipsyOnMe(div){
    $(div).tipsy('hide');
}
```

ANother way is to have a tipsy when you hover over that element (which I think is not what you want here but still),

Just put a title tag on your element on which you need a tipsy on hover and use

```
$(".mark_icon a").tipsy({live:true});
//works for me in all browsers
```