# jquery tipsy not firing onclick IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am using the jquery tipsy plugin to display colour names above colour swatch images.

I am trying to trigger a checkbox to be checked/unchecked when a user clicks on the image.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.label_check_colour').click(function(){
        setupLabelColour();
     });
}

function setupLabelColour() {
     if ($('.label_check_colour input').length) {
          $('.label_check_colour').each(function(){ 
              $(this).removeClass('c_on');
          });
$('.label_check_colour input:checked').each(function(){ 
    $(this).parent('label').addClass('c_on');
        });                
    };
};
```

HTML

```
<div class="selectableSwatch">
      <label class="label_check_colour" for="colour_1"><input type="checkbox" id="colour_1" name="colour_id[]" value="1" /><img class="colour_tip_1" width="20" src="img/colour-palette/1" /></label>
</div>
```

Everything works great in Firefox and Safari but not in IE8.

Help...please.

Comment: Have you checked that the css styles you are using work correctly in IE8?

Comment: yes I have because I can click to the right of the colour swatch image and it applies the onclick (checkbox) with all the correct styles. Its like the tipsy plugin is over the top of the element and not letting me click it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing  th if condition to this,

```
if ($('.label_check_colour input').length>0) {
```

and you have unwanted semi colons in  setupLabelColour function

```
function setupLabelColour() {
     if ($('.label_check_colour input').length) {
          $('.label_check_colour').each(function(){ 
              $(this).removeClass('c_on');
          });
         $('.label_check_colour input:checked').each(function(){ 
             $(this).parent('label').addClass('c_on');
         });                
    }
}
```

And you do not have the closing parentheses of document ready function. Here is full code http://jsfiddle.net/HMk9V/10/ . Try I think it is working now.

Comment: Still nothing. If I take the image out of the equation it works fine with the tipsy plugin so therefore it must be the image that is not allowing the click event